# Odd syntax: asterisk after scope operator (::)?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, member-pointers

Help me understand the following code snippet:

(foo.h)

```
class Foo
{
   public:
        typedef void (MyType::*Handler)(SomeOtherType* t);

        Foo(Handler handler) : handler_(handler) { }

   private:
        Handler handler_;
};
```

(mytype.h)

```
class MyType
{
     public:
          MyType() { }
          void fun1() { }
          void fun2() { }    
};
```

What exactly is the typedef in foo.h declaring here? I can see that it's a function pointer of some kind but what's the significance of the asterisk? It appears to be de-referencing a type (??) and somehow trying to "attach" the newly typedef'd pointer to the type of MyType (?!?).

Can someone shed some light here please? Really confused :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`void (MyType::*)(SomeOtherType* t)` is a pointer to a member function in class `MyType` that takes one argument (pointer to `SomeOtherType`) and returns nothing.

[FAQ Lite entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html).

Comment: Wowsers. I had no idea such a thing existed. Worse, the syntax is completely obtuse. These are just personal gripes though. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Daniel: Good news is you don't have to use that crappy syntax. Look into `std::function` and `std::bind` (or `boost::function`/`boost::bind` if you're still on C++03).

Comment: @CatPlusPlus You might also mention that `::*` is a single token, not a concatenation of `::` and `*`.  The wording in the original question makes me think that the poster isn't aware of this.

Comment: (removed previous comment; FAQ Lite already answers it). Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Pointer to a `MyType` member function returning `void` and taking pointer to `SomeOtherType` as a parameter.